# Non-restored Files Corrupted on System Restore

Tags: macos, file-corruption

I restored Mac OS X 10.6.2 today (was 10.6.3 and not booting) by copying the system over from a backup. **The data directories were not touched.**

**In the data directories, I'm seeing some files as 0 bytes, and getting permission-denied errors when copying, even when using `sudo cp`** or the Finder itself. Some programs, differently, take the files at face value and see no permission problems (such as zip), but they see the files as zero bytes, which would be game-over for recovery.

```
cp: .git/objects/fe/86b676974a44aa7f128a55bf27670f4a1073ca: could not copy extended attributes to /eraseme/blah/.git/objects/fe/86b676974a44aa7f128a55bf27670f4a1073ca: Operation not permitted
```

I have tried `sudo chown`, `sudo chmod -R 777` and `sudo chflags -R nouchg` which do not change the end result.

Strangely, this is only affecting my `.git` directories (perhaps because they start with a period, but renaming them -- which works -- does not change anything).

**What else can I do to take ownership of these files?**

**Edit:** This question comes from Stack Overflow because I originally thought it was a Git problem. It's definitely not (just) Git. Anyway, this is to help put some of the comments in context.

Comment: Seems to me that you're more likely to get an answer to this over on ServerFault, as it's probably an issue caused by the restore process, not something specific to GIT.

Comment: It's the same object id in every repository? Are they related to one another in some way? Also, are they clones or just local repos?

Comment: @ebneter, they are not related at all, and it seems that all the objects are showing as 0 bytes. Some are clones, some are local repos... mixed bag.

Comment: @Bevan, it's true that it's not exactly related to GIT, but I don't know how else to frame the question.

Comment: How did you do the backup and restore? Is it possible to look at the .git directories on the backup to see if the objects are non-zero size there?

Comment: @John Saunders, @Kate Ebneter: I haven't been clear. All of the directories in question WERE NEVER moved nor copied. I screwed up the operating system in a 10.6.3 upgrade, and I then downgraded manually (overlaying the system directories). These directories are the originals.

Comment: The combination of zero-byte files and xattrs sounds like HFS+ compression. http://arstechnica.com/apple/reviews/2009/08/mac-os-x-10-6.ars/3#footprint Is it possible that 10.6.3 introduced a new mode of HFS+ compression that is incompatible with 10.6.2? If so, maybe the files you are noticing were re-compressed with this incompatible method while you were running 10.6.3. You might want to poke around with hfsdebug http://osxbook.com/software/hfsdebug/ http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20090902223042255

Comment: @Chris Johnsen, this is possible but I don't think it's likely, just because 10.6.3 was only running for one day, and in that time I didn't touch many of the repositories that got screwed up. On the other hand, it's definitely worth taking a look around, and I will. What's weird is that only the .git dirs got screwed up and no others... boggling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though Git is using an advanced feature of the filesystem (hence the "extended attributes" in the message) which is not supported by the BSD-subsystem commands and, possibly, also by the backup system you're using.

Try using the backup system's own tools to restore these directories, if you used cp before.

If that doesn't work, you will probably need to re-clone these repos and/or switch to a more thorough backup system.

Comment: Thanks @Chromatix. The problem is that THESE DIRECTORIES WERE NEVER MOVED NOR COPIED. It's the system around them that has changed. +1 anyway.

Comment: I also adjusted the question to make all of this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running `fsck` (OK, I'm medium old school) or the Mac Disk Utility to ensure the file system is still consistent?  It's possible that whatever your 10.6.3 problem was, it affected the data partitions.

Comment: I ran the Disk Utility and "fixed permissions." Can I run fsck on a subtree?